# Wrong way Poincare duality for Calabi-Yau dg-algebras?

Tags: differential-graded-algebras, dg-categories, hochschild-homology

Let $A$ be a smooth compact Calabi-Yau dg $k$-algebra of dimension $w$. It is widely known (e.g. [Atsusi Takahashi](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.09099.pdf) proposition 2.4) that in such situation we have non canonical isomorphism of $A^{en}$-modules
$$A = A^{*}[-w]$$
So we have isomorphisms in $D(A^{en})$
$$\mathbb{R}Hom_{A^{en}}(A,A) = \mathbb{R}Hom_{A^{en}}(A,A^*[-w]) = \mathbb{R}Hom_{A^{en}}(A,\mathbb{R}Hom_k(A,k))[-w] = \mathbb{R}Hom_k(A \otimes^{L}_{A^{en}} A, k)[-w] = (A \otimes^L_{A^{en}} A)^* [-w] $$

So we can deduce that $HH_i(A,A) = HH^{w+i}(A,A)$. Great thing about that type of duality is that we use only compact Calabi-Yau structure and don't use smooth Calabi-Yau structure at all. Does my calculations correct or I missed something?

Comment: See https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.00619, where for a smooth dg algebra there is a notion of a left Calabi-Yau structure which in particular is an isomorphism $A\cong A^![d]$ and for a proper (=compact) dg algebra there is a notion of a right Calabi-Yau structure which in particular is an isomorphism $A\cong A^*[-d]$. The former is a version of Ginzburg's Calabi-Yau algebras while the latter is a version of symmetric Frobenius algebras.

Comment: @PavelSafronov Thank you! I have read the paper you are talking about. But I think the paper don't answer on my question directly. Does $A = A^*[-d]$ in $Mod-A^{en}$ always automatically implies $HH_i = HH^{i+d}$?

Comment: For any dg algebra (not necessarily Calabi-Yau or proper) you have an isomorphism $(HH_\bullet(A, A))^*\cong HH^\bullet(A, A^*)$ (basically, by your argument). Then if you have an isomorphism $A = A^*[-d]$ in $A-A$-bimodules, you get an isomorphism $(HH_\bullet(A, A))^*\cong HH^{\bullet-d}(A, A)$. I think the answer to your question is that your calculations are correct (apart from the missing dual, but I guess it's a typo).

Comment: @PavelSafronov Two short questions. Am I understand correctly that $H^i(M^*)= H^{-i}(M)$ and $HH_i(A,A)=H^{-i}(A \otimes^L_{A^{en}}  A)$?

Comment: The second is correct. For the first: $H^i(M^*) = H^{-i}(M)^*$.

Comment: @PavelSafronov There is something strange in your identity ($HH_i^* = HH^{i-d}$). Assume that $\bullet = 0$, $d = 1$, $A=End(G)$, $G$ any generator of $D^b Coh(E)$ (e.g. $\mathcal{O} + \mathcal{O}_p, p \in E$), $E$ - elleptic curve. So in this case we have $HH_0^* = HH^{-1}$ but this is definitely not true because $HH^{-1} = 0$ and $HH_0^* \neq 0$ in this case. Am I wrong?

Comment: It seems like we both mixed up right and left because $RHom(A,B[d]) = RHom(A,B)[d]$ so in your case formula must be $(HH_\bullet(A,A))^* = HH^{\bullet+d}(A,A)$